# Installing / Updating Docker Desktop on Mac without admin

Tags: macos, installation, docker, non-admin

I have a Mac where I do not have admin rights. I have requested and received temporary admin rights on the machine to install Docker. I just recently read that if we can install any software in a directory other than the System Applications directory without admin rights.

But when I start the Docker.app from that directory, I get a pop-up that requests admin id / password.

I can put that info in for next 2 days, as the admin is for very limited time.

I have two questions :

- Why am I being asked for admin info, if I am installing it at a location other than Systems Applications folder.
- This doesn't allow to update the Docker version without putting the admin info again. Since my admin is very temporary and I will not be able to get this access again and again, how should I install it initially so that I will be able to update to newer versions. Otherwise, I will be stuck at the today's version

I am new to Mac.

Appreciate any pointers / help

(It may appear to be cross-posting because I had asked this question on SO, but it was suggested that I ask it here )

Thanks

Comment: idk Docker specifically, but it will depend on what it needs those admin perms for. If it's to install some system-level components, it will only need that perm once. Test - run, give perms, do some small task. Quit, reboot, Try again.

Comment: I tried it for Docker and if you need to update the version, it does ask you for admin credentials again.  And, as I said above, I will not get that repeatedly.  So, does it mean, I will be stuck at the version I install today, without being able to update it periodically without admin credentials?

Comment: I don't know specifically when it will ask for admin perms, but any time it does… you're stuck.

Comment: Ok, so there is no mechanism I can employ that will allow later updates without admin, if I initially install it a certainway with admin access?

Comment: again… I don't know specifically when it will ask for admin perms… if it asks, you're stuck. There is no way around this. That's precisely what admin perms are for, to prevent non-admins from making system changes.

Answer (score 0):

Docker must be installed by a user with admin privileges. There's no way to get around that. The docker daemon needs admin privileges to run.

You also won't be able to update Docker Desktop without admin privileges.

However, you *can* install Docker Desktop using your temporary admin privileges and set it to start up when your non-admin user logs in.

### 1. Install Docker Desktop normally

Don't bother trying to install Docker to your user's Applications directory. Just install it normally to the System Applications directory (`/Applications`). Enter your temporary admin creds when prompted.

### 2. Set Docker to start when your non-admin user logs in

System Preferences > Users & Groups

1. Click the name of your **non-admin** user.
2. Click the lock icon in the lower left and enter your temporary admin creds.
3. Click the *Login Items* tab.
4. Click the `+` button and select *Docker* from the list.

[image: docker login items]

Now when you log in as the non-admin user, Docker will start up automatically. It will work without needing admin privileges.